# google cloud storage - I can't edit the permissions of my objects even though I am the project owner

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I use the following Java code to add an object to google cloud storage with public read access so anyone can read the file:

```
try {
     gcsService.createOrReplace(file, new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
                            .mimeType("image/jpeg")
                            .acl("public-read").build(),
                            ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
        } catch (IOException ex){
            // catch error
        }
```

But when I go to cloud storage in the GCP console, I get this notification and also this error if I try to edit the permissions of the file:

> Since you are not authorized to know the public access status of this
> object, it is possible that the public URL displayed is not valid.

[image]

Is there something I can do when I write the file to cloud storage so it has both the public-read permission and also allows me, the project owner, to have permission to edit it's permissions?

Seems kind of silly how I cannot edit the permissions of my own objects when I am the project owner.

**EDIT:**

I was also considering using the new cloud storage api. Here is the code I have so far. How can I make the ACL be for the project owner (me) as well as have it be publicly readable?

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucket, object);

BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId)
        .setContentType(mimeType)
        .setAcl(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), READER)))
        .build();

Blob output = storage.create(blobInfo, data);
```

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra It didn't really help because I was looking for a code solution in Java rather than just a broad description of how permissions work. Your answer just sounds more like documentation instead of taking the code I wrote in the question and adding/subtracting from it to make it work. Thanks though!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that you actually need is the "code to make the ACL for the project owner (you) as well as have it be publicly readable?". I will share a [GitHub comment link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/1012#issuecomment-219534395) which I think will help you.

Comment: Focus on the point where it mentions that `storage.create(coverBlob, coverImage,
    BlobTargetOption.predefinedAcl(PredefinedAcl.PUBLIC_READ))`;
Sets the predefined ACL to PUBLIC_READ. The PUBLIC_READ predefined ACL corresponds to setting the following permissions:
`Object owner gets OWNER access`, `allUsers get READER access` while `.acl(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(User.ofAllUsers(), Role.READER)))`
Sets the ACL for the blob with just setting the following permission:
`allUsers get READER access`

Comment: Also, here is the [code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/1012#issuecomment-219852535) where you could give owner access to a single user account or all project owners. Let me know if it worked for you. I would like to improve my answer so that it looks less documentation like and more relevant to your answer. Have a great day!

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra That helps a lot. Can you add your code to the answer? May make it more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `storage.buckets.getIamPolicy` is used to read bucket IAM policies and `storage.buckets.setIamPolicy` is used to update bucket IAM policies.
[The storage.objects.getIamPolicy and storage.objects.setIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions)  permissions do not apply to buckets with [uniform bucket-level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access) enabled. So when you enable uniform bucket-level access on a bucket, Access Control Lists (ACLs) are disabled, and only bucket-level Identity and Access Management (IAM) permissions grant access to that bucket and the objects it contains. So first check if you have enabled [uniform bucket-level access /  fine-grained permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#choose_between_uniform_and_fine-grained_access) for your bucket when you created it using the [various options to view bucket metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-bucket-information#display-bucket-properties) ( except XML API)

Access to GCS resources is not recursive. Owning a project or a bucket within that project does not necessarily imply that you also have certain permissions to a specific object. Owning the bucket does imply that you can list or delete the object, but that's it.
The best resource to figure out which built-in IAM roles can do which things is the Google Cloud Platform [IAM Permissions Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).
On that page, CTRL-F for other permission you're interested in and you will see the roles that grant it on the right-hand column. Note that project owner (roles/owner) is not in the list of roles that grant this permission.

And coming to how to make individual objects publicly readable, go through this [Java code sample in documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects).  Again,  if your bucket uses [uniform bucket-level acces](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-uniform-bucket-level-access#view-status)s, you cannot use these steps. Instead, grant [public readability to all objects in the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets), or use [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). Maybe this is the reason you are getting the error, as you have uniform-bucket-level access permissions on the bucket and you are trying out the not possibles.